# Like a root but not quite the same

Tags: linux, security, permissions, acl

Is it possible to create a linux user group that has all other rights just like the root user, with the exception that it can only read files in /var/log folder, but can not change or delete them? Of course such a user must not be able to change anything in /var/log with chown or chmod, but otherwise it must behave just like the real root user.

Comment: `/var` and `/var/log` have normally read+execute permissions for all users, so any user should be ok.

Comment: yes, but user like a root can write to files in /var/log, and i want to avoid this - i want to reserve this "privilege" only to real root user.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean: with any other user you can go through these files without the option to write them. Or you mean to have a root user with privileges all around except on those dirs?

Comment: Yes, I mean to have a root user (or, better, "root user") with privileges all around except on those dirs!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Don't forget about groups.